# I blew up Vault 19 -- so why does the ending act like I didn't?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I just finished New Vegas, siding with the NCR. This was my fourth run-through. This time around, I blew up Vault 19. (It seems that being "Very Good" karmically involved a lot of blowing up established environments -- Vault 19, the Brotherhood, I could go on ... )

So I get to the end-game, and I'm told that the Vault 19 Powder Gangers continued to torment the wasteland for years, preying on citizens of the NCR.

What? I **blew them up.** Like, exploded the Vault. Kablooey! Is this a glitch, or does the game just not have a separate ending slide for, "the Courier destroyed all the evil ex-cons and the NCR lived happily ever after?"

Comment: Knowing Bethesda... sounds like a bug / the quest fails to set the vault 19 ending flag properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Fallout New Vegas Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_endings) you have to talk to Philip Lem about the future of the Powder gangers, otherwise you get the incorrect ending. There are four different endings for the Vault 19 Powder gangers.

Comment: I was literally just reading that now. (It took me a while to find the "endings" page on the Wiki.) Is that the first conversation? Because I went through the entire tree with him before going down there. Indeed, I initially planned to just destroy the sulfur deposits and let them surrender -- but my explosives skill (even with Mentats and a Patriot's Cookbook) wasn't high enough.

Comment: @John I don't know exactly which conversation is meant there. My interpretation is: FNV is just buggy.

Comment: @LOL, probably the case! :)